# How to hide "Unknown configuration setting" warnings in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings, settings

I get following warnings in vscode and I want just to hide them:
[image: "unknown configuration setting" warning]

How do I hide them, is it even possible?

**Background**
I use several extensions in vscode, and on different machines I have different sets of extensions activated.

Particularly, on one machine I use [Mocha Test runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter) while on another machine, I use [Mocha sidebar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar).
The `settings.json` file is part of the repository.

These warnings pollute my Problems window where I just want to see project's lint errors / warnings.

Comment: If the settings do not apply to the workspace, you could move them from the workspace scope to the user settings scope for each machine. So in one machine's user settings are all the _mocha test runner_ settings and in the other's the _mocha sidebar_ settings

Comment: If its possible, I would prefer to keep everything in the workspace scope, so I can assure that everywhere (for me and other developers) the same config settings are applied.